# Java socket server only displays messages received after the connection closes

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, message

I am trying to write a code for a simple server, that receives messages from a client. The connection is succesful but once the server connects with the client the messages are not displayed on the screen. After I close the connection from the client side, the server receives all the messages in one go.

I need to receive the messages line by line because each line needs to de processed individually and in real time (I am using HMM for driver's actions recognition).

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanko you very much.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ServerSocket my_server = null;
    String received_message;
    DataOutputStream output = null; 
    Socket socket_connected = null;

    try {
        my_server = new ServerSocket(9090);
    }
    catch (IOException excepcion) {
        System.out.println(excepcion);
    }
    try {
        socket_connected = my_server.accept();
        BufferedReader entrada = null;      

        while (socket_connected.isConnected() == true){ 
            entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket_connected.getInputStream()));
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket_connected.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Confirmando conexion al cliente....");           

            received_message = entrada.readLine();
            System.out.println(received_message);
            entrada.close();
            output.close();         
        }

        socket_connected.close();
    }
    catch (IOException excepcion) {
        System.out.println(excepcion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do You know `flush` method? You can use it after write in the socket (client side or server side)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution and I would like to share here.

My client was a Visual Basic Application and I have a Java Server. The client was sending the messages without an End Of Line character so the entrada.readLine(); would be waiting for a signal that the message was over before displaying it (what never happened).
The solution was to add a End Of Line character at the end of the client messages and everything worked out well in the end.

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side, do you flush your output stream ?

When closing the connection, all remaining data are flushed but before that, they only are if there is enough "waiting" data to be sent.